# Order by Asc in Query formula with blanks on top

Tags: google-sheets

I am wanting to order `E` by `asc` but get blanks at the top of the page. Is there a way of filtering the blanks without removing them through a select, not null select.

```
=QUERY(Staging!$A$2:$Z,"SELECT  Z,D,B,J,P,E,S,Q,O WHERE Y is null and S is not null order by E")
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, your existing formula works but you want the blanks at the bottom instead of the top?

If so:

```
=QUERY(Staging!$A$2:$Z,"SELECT Z,D,B,J,P,E,S,Q,O WHERE Y is null and S is not null order by E DESC")
```